# How do I get HDMI to DVI to work @ 1920x1200?

Tags: hdmi, dvi

I can't get my Notebook (ASUS F9E with HDMI output) and monitor (NEC LCD2690WUXi with DVI input) to work with native 1920x1200 resolution (D-SUB works OK)
I have tried severals adapters, with no result (display settings is limited to 1280x720)
Can anybody tell me the solution?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot go above this resolution because your laptop's screen is limited to that, and thus it will be duplicated on this monitor. You can set up an "Extended Display" to make the 2nd monitor 1920x1200 though. On Windows, right click on the desktop, and choose to extend the display there, and then it will allow the 2nd monitor to use that resolution.

[image: Screen Resolution]

Where it says "Duplicate display" (Not shown in my image), choose to extend, hit apply, and it should automatically fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The HDMI output of your laptop may be limited to HD resolutions, which 1920x1200 is not. Try 1920x1080 (1080p) instead.

Unless of course, your hardware is limited to 720p, I have no idea. You should probably check if that information is in the user-manual in the Specifications sections.

Answer (score 0):

You may find your monitor has TWO DVI inputs - such as on my LaCie 526.

Only one of them is digital - which explains why the other is limited to 1280x768.

Switched to the other connector and I instantly got 1920x1080 :-)

(I had auto select enabled in the monitor's menu, so check there too if you have two inputs and one doesn't appear to work at all)